# UI loads on double click - iOS only

Tags: xamarin.forms

This happens only to some of my pages and on iOS only. When I click on a button which should open new page it calls InitializeComponent(); of the page but does not call OnAppearing() until I click somewhere else again. Same thing with labels, for example when I click on a checkbox label should increment, but it does not get updated until I click on the page. Is something blocking my UI or what might be an issue.
Here is an example which should open a new page - when I click on label "Create_Batch" it calls InitializeComponent() of SubmitInvoicesPage but does not call OnAppearing() until I click somewhere else, again it only happens on iOS, Android works perfectly fine.

```
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate Create_Batch}"  Style="{DynamicResource FontLabel}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BuildABatchCommand}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
```

```
public ICommand BuildABatchCommand { get; set; }  
this.BuildABatchCommand = new Command(async () => { await BuildABatch(); });

public async Task BuildABatch()
        {
            SubmittingBatch = true;            
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new SubmitInvoicesPage(this));          
        }
```

**EDIT:**
It happens to the pages where I am passing (this).

Comment: Can you post some code snippets?

Comment: @AndroDevil added

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with those codes. Can you share codes in SubmitInvoicesPage?